# Disable answers, but keep crash reporting for Fabric

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

The line above will enable both answers analytics and crash reporting. I want to disable answers analytics in some environments. Is there any way to do this?

I could make a separate target for each environment, but they would be really hard to manage in this case.

Comment: if no-one can answer this contact the Fabric support team they have always been super helpful for me.

Comment: I agree with @WarrenBurton

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Currently, there isn't a way to do this. The inverse (enabled Answers, but disable Crashlytics) is possible. I can let the team know you'd like to see it added.

Comment: @MikeBonnell: imo Fabric should have the option to disable Answers (while Crashlytics still enables). From my side, I only use Crashlytics for crash reporting. Answers is quite good, but it drains battery by calling frequency.

Comment: Thanks @nahung89 for the feedback and thoughts, will share it with the team!

Comment: @MikeBonnell It could be also useful for disabling Answers in development builds

Comment: @MikeBonnell Is there any update one this? Still we are seeing the same problem. Unable to switch off Answers. I am using com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7

Comment: No updates on this @Aram. If you want to keep debug data out of Answers, then I recommend using a different bundle id or package name. If you need Answers disabled entirely for an app, contact support through the link in your Fabric dashboard.

Comment: Thanks @MikeBonnell